# Vuetify dynamically load data table rows

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify datatable like this

```
<v-data-table :items="items" :headers="headers" :search="search">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <td>{{props.item.id}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.make}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.year}}</td>

            </template>
          </v-data-table>
```

Instead of this, what I want is load these td elements using a v-for

I tried

`<td v-for="i in headers" :key="i">{{props.item.i.text}}</td>`

How do I do this in vuetify. Also my vuetify version is 1.5.5

This is my code pen
https://codepen.io/pathum-kalhan/pen/ZEzMEQG

Answer (score 1):

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <td v-for="(prop, key) of props.item" :key="key" :v-text="prop" />
</template>
```

...works (for now).
Note the usage of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

But this will output a `<td>` for each property of your items. Which means that if any one of your items gets an aditional property (own or inherited), it will break the table layout.

A safer way is to use helper spreading method, to enforce the structure of the output object:

```
methods: {
  spreadItem(item) {
    const { id, make, year } = item;
    return { id, make, year };
  }
}
```

and, in template:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <td v-for="(prop, key) of spreadItem(props.item)" 
       :key="key"
       :v-text="prop" />
</template>
```

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/PoYdPYa). This will not add extra cells when a few items have additional props (unless you add them to the `spreadItem` method and the `headers`, of course, in which case they'll show up as an additional column).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following template:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-data-table :items="items" :headers="headers" :search="search">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <template v-for"column in headers">
                <td>{{ column.text }}</td>
              </template>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in `v-for` like below

```
<td v-for="(key,index) in Object.keys(props.item)" :key="index">{{props.item[key]}}</td>
```

> Please check below code snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [{id:1,make:'bmw',year:2019},{id:2,make:'benz',year:2019}],
      headers: [
        { text: 'Id', value: 'id' },

        { text: 'Make', value: 'make' },
        { text: 'Year', value: 'year' }],
    search:""
        
  })
})
```

```css
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-data-table :items="items" :headers="headers" :search="search">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <td v-for="(key,index) in Object.keys(props.item)" :key="index">{{props.item[key]}}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```